# Batch script: copy the newest folder in the directory that is nonempty

Tags: batch-file

I'm having issues with what I feel like should not be hard to figure out.

I have a folder of folders with version numbers 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0.2 for example. I want to grab the newest **modified** folder that is  **nonempty** meaning it has a file somewhere in it (which will always have the same name and location under that folder), not just more folders, and copy that file elsewhere.

Right now I have

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /od') do (set latest=%%i)
```

to find the newest folder but that's not working, it's returning a random file instead. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question clarifying 'non-empty': does a folder count as empty if it has a zero-length file in one of it's subfolders?

Comment: In this context the only file in the folder/subfolders will have a specific name, so if that were less complicated I could search by that, but I figured non-empty would be a simpler parameter.

Comment: "copy **it** elsewhere" - copy **what**? The directory? The file found? if more than one file, which? the first, the last, a random one?

Comment: You specify "newest modified folder" yet use `/t:c` which is the create-timestamp, not the modified timestamp. Please clarify.

Comment: The file. I should clarify, if there's a file in that folder, it will be in the same path, "./x64/abc.exe" every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
set "latest="
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') do if not defined latest if exist ".\%%i\x64\abc.exe" set "latest=%%i\x64\abc.exe"
```

should work, looking in each directory in reverse-date-order for the file `.\x64\abc.exe`, and stopping the procedure once the variable `latest` has been set.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry about this folks, I misread the title and thought this was a *bash* script rather than a *batch* script. I'm leaving it up on the off chance it may be useful getting to the correct answer.

Assuming that your directory looks something like this:

```
1.1/
1.2/some_file
2.4/some_other_file
```

Then this command:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.' -print0 |\
   xargs -0 -r -n1 -P0 du -s |\
   egrep -v '^0\s+' |\
   cut -f2 |\
   cut -d'/' -f2- |\
   sort -n |\
   head -n1
```

Should get you the non-empty file or folder with the smallest number.

Here's what is going on:

1. Find all files in the current directory which is not named '.', emit as a null-separated list.
2. Take each file in a separate process and run `du` to determine the size of each file/folder.
3. Filter out any that have zero size.
4. Remove the sizes (no longer needed).
5. Remove the "./" in front of the file names that `du` includes as part of it's output.
6. Sort the files by name (`-n` is numeric sort, this assumes that there is no prefix in front of the numbers. `sort` can handle it if there is, check the manpage).
7. Discard all but the first line.